# 2D Array is still null

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array in class Board to host objects of type Ship.  The constructor of the Board class initiates the 2D array with ship objects, however it still remains null when I check it out.

```
public class Ship{

    private int tons; // 1 element in 2d array

    public Ship(){
        this.tons=1;
    }

     public Ship(int t){
        this.tons=t;
    }

    public int getTons(){
        return this.tons;
    }

     public void setTons(){
        this.tons = 1;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Board{

    private Ship battleShip[][];
    private Random rnd=new Random();

    public Board(){
      //setup board with null values
      Ship battleShip[][] = new Ship[5][5]; 

      // initialize
      for (int r=0; r < 5; r++ )
           for (int c=0; c < 5; c++ )
            battleShip[r][c]= new Ship();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared one additional variable `battleShip` in constructor. use the class member variable which you already defined in class.

```
private Ship battleShip[][];//<------------- use this
```

The constructor should be modify to this

```
public Board(){
  //setup board with null values
  battleShip = new Ship[5][5]; //<----------  now member variable is initialed

  // initialize
  for (int r=0; r < 5; r++ )
       for (int c=0; c < 5; c++ )
        battleShip[r][c]= new Ship();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

doing this:

```
public Board(){
      //setup board with null values
      Ship battleShip[][] = new Ship[5][5];
```

shadows the class member `battleShip` and keep as non initialized field in the class